# Combination of two arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, combinations

What is the Ruby way to achieve following?

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]
```

I want an array:

```
=> [f(1,3) ,f(1,4) , f(2,3) ,f(2,4)]
```

Comment: @lucasarruda that's not quite the same as what OP is asking. Zip will create an array of `[a[0], b[0]]` and `[a[1], b[1]]`. It wouldn't include `[a[0], b[1]]`. `a.zip(b) => [[1,3],[2,4]]`

Comment: Thanks @KNejad , you are correct. Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can use `product` to get the cartesian product of the arrays first, then collect the function results.

```
a.product(b) => [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
```

So you can use `map` or `collect` to get the results. They are different names for the same method.

```
a.product(b).collect { |x, y| f(x, y) }
```

Comment: Product is only built-in as of 1.9.

Comment: Product is in 1.8.7 - I use it to do exactly what Pierr is asking

Comment: @FloatingRock that is incorrect it's combination not permuation. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-product

Comment: @FloatingRock Not so.  The first element of each item will always come from the first list, the second element from the second list, and so on.  It's all possible combinations of elements, but they are never reordered, so it's not permutations.

Comment: And if you have c=[5,6] and d=[7,8] you can do `[a,b,c,d].reduce([[]]){|r,e| r=r.product(e)}.map{|x| x.flatten}`

Comment: For three arrays ```a.product(b,c)``` and so forth (till you run out of memory).  Ruby is so cool!

Answer (score 11):

```
a.map {|x| b.map {|y| f(x,y) } }.flatten
```

Note: On 1.8.7+ you can add `1` as an argument to flatten, so you'll still get correct results when `f` returns an array.

Here's an abstraction for an arbitrary number of arrays:

```
def combine_arrays(*arrays)
  if arrays.empty?
    yield
  else
    first, *rest = arrays
    first.map do |x|
      combine_arrays(*rest) {|*args| yield x, *args }
    end.flatten
      #.flatten(1)
  end
end

combine_arrays([1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]) do |x,y,z| x+y+z end
# => [10, 11, 12, 11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14, 11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15, 12, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15, 14, 15, 16]
```

Comment: This will work though I'm not sure if it is the best way (though can't think of a better one so +1)

Comment: I wish I could +2 for the combination of arbitrary amount of arrays. Very cool!

Comment: i came out with this too.. but then i knew theres should be an easier way to do it... +1 for this but the @Aaron Hinni answer its cleaner

Answer (score 5):

Facets has `Array#product` which will give you the cross product of arrays.  It is also aliased as the `** operator` for the two-array case.  Using that, it would look like this:

```
require 'facets/array'
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]

(a.product b).collect {|x, y| f(x, y)}
```

If you are using Ruby 1.9, [`product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-product) is a built-in Array function.

Comment: Why do people keep saying Array#product is a 1.9ism?  It's in 1.8.7, at least.