# Create nested arrays (2D) by merging arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, nested

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combination of two arrays in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543614/combination-of-two-arrays-in-ruby)

```
Faces = "Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Ten Jack Queen King Ace"
Suits = "Spades Clubs Hearts Diamonds"
Face = []
Face = Faces.split * 4
Suits.split
```

I am seeking to take the `suits.split` `array` and feed each suit 13 times into `Face` to create a 2D array that will look something like `[["Two", "Spades"],["Three", "Spades"]... ["Ace", "Diamonds"]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted in the question linked by Sunny, you're looking for `product`:

```
Faces.product Suits
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, variables should are in the form of `snake_case` and constants in `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`. Its hard to say if you're trying to create constants or variables.

You can also instantiate your array in a simpler way using `%w{elements here}`.

Skim the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) to understand what's going on here.

```
faces = %w{Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Ten Jack Queen King Ace}
 => ["Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"] 
suites = %w{Spades Clubs Hearts Diamonds}
 => ["Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds"] 
 faces.product(suites)
 => [["Two", "Spades"], ["Two", "Clubs"], ["Two", "Hearts"], ["Two", "Diamonds"], ["Three", "Spades"], ["Three", "Clubs"], ["Three", "Hearts"], ["Three", "Diamonds"], ["Four", "Spades"], ["Four", "Clubs"], ["Four", "Hearts"], ["Four", "Diamonds"], ["Five", "Spades"], ["Five", "Clubs"], ["Five", "Hearts"], ["Five", "Diamonds"], ["Six", "Spades"], ["Six", "Clubs"], ["Six", "Hearts"], ["Six", "Diamonds"], ["Seven", "Spades"], ["Seven", "Clubs"], ["Seven", "Hearts"], ["Seven", "Diamonds"], ["Eight", "Spades"], ["Eight", "Clubs"], ["Eight", "Hearts"], ["Eight", "Diamonds"], ["Nine", "Spades"], ["Nine", "Clubs"], ["Nine", "Hearts"], ["Nine", "Diamonds"], ["Ten", "Spades"], ["Ten", "Clubs"], ["Ten", "Hearts"], ["Ten", "Diamonds"], ["Jack", "Spades"], ["Jack", "Clubs"], ["Jack", "Hearts"], ["Jack", "Diamonds"], ["Queen", "Spades"], ["Queen", "Clubs"], ["Queen", "Hearts"], ["Queen", "Diamonds"], ["King", "Spades"], ["King", "Clubs"], ["King", "Hearts"], ["King", "Diamonds"], ["Ace", "Spades"], ["Ace", "Clubs"], ["Ace", "Hearts"], ["Ace", "Diamonds"]]
```

Keep in mind product is only available in Ruby 1.9 >=.